# Converting back to HTML in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am parsing HTML content:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_content)
```

I am replacing text in the p tag with class name 'pubdate online'.

```
doc.css("p.pubdate.online").each do |node|
   node.content = self.send("#{article_type}_released_at").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
 end
```

And I am trying to convert the parsed HTML back to original HTML.

```
 doc.to_html
```

But now the `doc.to_html` does not have the `<DOCTYPE!>` or `<head>` tag or the `<body>` tag. So the problem is when using the HTML I get the raw HTML code instead of a HTML page. Help me to convert the doc back to original HTML content with replaced text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_content)
```

I was not able to reproduce your issue but what stuck out to me is that you're parsing `html_content` as a fragment rather than as a full document.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/modifying_an_html_xml_document.html), can you try this:

```
node = doc.at_css("p.pubdate.online")
node.content = self.send("#{article_type}_released_at").strftime("%B %d, %Y")
doc.to_html
```